# How to wire them together by Spring annotations

Tags: spring, annotations, autowired

I got a web application, and I have to wire it's components (A,B,C) together instead of direct method calls.

So, I dont know how can I wire object instances together when they need additional instances  in the constructor.

I think in thats why the we can use (bean ... constructor-args ...) in application context.
But I dont know what if I want to use annotations.

I made a simple example to demostrate the concrete problem

```
class A
{
   protected B b;
   ...  
   public func1(){
   obj0 = makeObj0();
   b = new B(obj0)
   }

   public Obj0 makeObj0() {...}         
}

class B extends C
{
  protected Obj0 obj0;

  public B(Obj0 obj0){

   super(obj0, "foo", new Obj1); //there is no another way to construct B, C 
       setObj0(obj0);
  } 

  public void setObj0(obj){ obj0=obj;}
}
```

What is the best way to wiring A,B,(C) together (by annotations) because B, C needs additinal arguments right in their constructor.

Sorry for the lenghty explanation, and thanks for the tips in advance.

Cs

Answer (score 1):

```
@Autowired
public B(..) {..}
```

will autowire all arguments. If you need additional arguments - then don't use constructor injection. Use setter/field injection. Provide an empty constructor and have `@Autowired` on each field that you need.

Comment: Thanks, give me time to try them.
I appreciate your helpfulness.

Comment: One more thing, is there any tools which helps me to follow what Spring does in the background in point of DI view ? (other than Spring IDE)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. if you try with @Resource when initiating the B-class.

```
    class A
{
   @Resource(name = "b")
   protected B b;
   ...  
   public func1(){
   obj0 = makeObj0();
   b = new B(obj0)
   }

   public Obj0 makeObj0() {...}         
}
```

Then if you need to Autowire in B or C I find hard to tell.

Comment: Thanks, give me time to try them.
I appreciate your helpfulness.